# Laravel и Angular, что писать в .htaccess?

Tags: .htaccess, angularjs, laravel

как сделать так, что бы о адресу example.com был доступен сайт на laravel,а по адресу example.com/admin грузилось ангуляровское приложение?
Структура сервера

```
root
-laravel (сайт на laravel)
-admin (приложение на angular)
```

Пробовал вот так, не работает

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
    Options +FollowSymLinks
    RewriteEngine On
    RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]
    RewriteRule ^/admin/$ /admin/app/index.html$1 [L]
</IfModule>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Добавьте еще один маршрут в Laravel и отдавайте `index.html`.

Либо, исправьте правила. У вас там две проблемы:

1. Первое правило перекрывает второе
2. Похоже, Apache2 не любит слеш вначале (перед admin)

Получится так:

```
...
RewriteRule ^admin/$ /admin/app/index.html$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]
...
```

Или так:

```
...
RewriteRule ^/?admin/$ /admin/app/index.html$1 [L]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ laravel/public/$1 [L]
...
```

Немного ссылок:

- [Learn Apache mod_rewrite](http://www.sitepoint.com/apache-mod_rewrite-examples/)
- [An In-Depth Guide to mod_rewrite for Apache](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/a-deeper-look-at-mod_rewrite-for-apache--net-6708)
- [Отладка htaccess](http://htaccess.mwl.be/)